# pythonic way to print out column conditions in database (psql)

Tags: python, ruby, automation, psql

I have a nasty error with no direction when using factory boy to make fake models:

`DataError: value too long for type character varying(2)`

Is there a pythonic (or ruby) way to print out only the names of columns that are varchar(2) type in the database?  I'd assume it's in some pgadmin3 metadata? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Postgres query, I think this does what you're looking for.

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='some_table' AND data_type='varchar(2)';
```

This just selects all the `varchar(2)` columns in a specific table, but you can drop that part to get them throughout the entire database. You can also add in `table_schema='some_schema'` for just a certain schema in the database.

As far as a pythonic or ruby way to do it, I don't know of one, other than running that query in psycopg or some other Postgres adapter.

More info on [information_schema.columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html)